# Android WebView <input type="file"> not working

Tags: android, webview, camera, gallery, capture

I have kept an html file on a website.

https://pinapakait.com/cam/testcam.html

It has following simple input type file code
input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"

It is opening files, camera options when opened in mobile through web browser. But now opening in web view of android.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Gave following permissions

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

set following settings for web view.

```
    setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true)
    setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    setDomStorageEnabled(true)
    setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
    setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON)
    setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
    setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON)
    setAppCacheEnabled(true)

    setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY)
    setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true)
    setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true)
    setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)
    setBuiltInZoomControls(true)

    setPluginsEnabled(true)
    setAllowFileAccess(true)
    setAllowContentAccess(true)
    setSupportZoom(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with webview and after googling it I found this solution by extending WebChromeClient .

```
    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    DetailsFragmentWebView context;
    public ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessageAboveL;
    public Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    public MyWebChromeClient(DetailsFragmentWebView context){
        this.context = context;
        //this.mCapturedImageURI = mCapturedImageURI;
        //this.mUploadMessage = mUploadMessage;
        //this.mUploadMessageAboveL = mUploadMessageAboveL;
    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsgAboveL, String acceptType){

        // Update message
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        mUploadMessageAboveL = uploadMsgAboveL;
        try{

            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            context.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context.getActivity(), "Chrome Exception:"+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg , mUploadMessageAboveL, acceptType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        openFileChooser(null ,filePathCallback , "");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And set your webview to use this class :

```
MyWebChromeClient  myChromeClient = new myChromeClient(this);
webView.webChromeClient = myChromeClient;
```

Also you need to add this code to your Activity :

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == myChromeClient.mUploadMessage && null == myChromeClient.mUploadMessageAboveL) return
        val result = if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) null
                        else if (data!=null) data.data
                        else myChromeClient.mCapturedImageURI
        if (myChromeClient.mUploadMessageAboveL != null) {
            onActivityResultAboveL(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        } else if (myChromeClient.mUploadMessage != null) {
            myChromeClient.mUploadMessage?.onReceiveValue(result)
            myChromeClient.mUploadMessage = null
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private fun onActivityResultAboveL(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || myChromeClient.mUploadMessageAboveL == null)
        return
    var results: Array<Uri>? = null
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (intent != null) {
            val dataString = intent.dataString
            val clipData = intent.clipData
            if (clipData != null) {
                results = Array<Uri>(clipData.itemCount) { _->return Unit}
                for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                    val item = clipData.getItemAt(i)
                    results[i] = item.uri
                }
            }
            if (dataString != null)
                results = arrayOf(Uri.parse(dataString))
        }else if (myChromeClient.mCapturedImageURI!=null)
            results = arrayOf(myChromeClient.mCapturedImageURI)
    }
    myChromeClient.mUploadMessageAboveL?.onReceiveValue(results)
    myChromeClient.mUploadMessageAboveL = null
}
```